# SQL , Extracting a particular data from a column

Tags: sql, substring

Comments

---

'teacherName: Andrew Cribbs, comment: No level change chosen by the trainer'
'teacherName: Andrew Cribbs, comment: No level change chosen by the trainer'
'teacherName: Andrew Cribbs, comment: No level change chosen by the trainer'

Above is the column(Comments) which contains data, Any idea on how to extract the Name(Andrew Cribbs)

Comment: hi can you explain more? i couldn't understand your question. Are these columns? "teacherName , Comment "

Comment: Comment----> Column Name
'teacherName..... -----> Datas under 'Comment' column

I want to extract the Name of the teacher Eg, Andrew Cribbs or Andrew .P Cribbs
and put it in a separate columns

Comment: If you actually want to find 'Andrew Cribbs' it would be easy but finding *person names* in general in a string column where users have stored all kinds of comments would be impossible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle can you use this script that use ":" and "," as separators:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(regexp_substr('teacherName: Andrew Cribbs, comment: No level change chosen by the trainer', '[^:]+', 1, 2), '[^,]+', 1, 1)
    AS teachername
  FROM dual;
```

Thank you